# What are the good ways to maintain the bicycle during the rainy season?

Tags: preventative-maintenance, rain, corrosion

I have a bicycle. I ride it everyday because it was my primary vehicle. When I was going to campus or another places, I used it. Currently, the raining season is on my country.  I would like to maintain my bicycle and keep it in good condition. This includes preventing a bicycle chain from corroding.

Also, another use cases which can be happened while raining season.

Any good suggestion for that cases?

Comment: Can you tell us what sort of bottom bracket you have? Also, what brand are your hubs? Type of breaks?

Comment: Mainly, keep the chain oiled.  For wet weather you should ask for a "wet" chain lubricant at the bike shop, though a plain heavy motor oil will work.  Be sure to wipe the chain with a rag before applying new oil.

Comment: Running a beater bike in the rain/snow is a good idea if you can have one.

Comment: @Vorac, actually I didn't know the details of my bicycle. But, I can tell you the details from http://www.unitedbike.com/id/index.php?cmd=productdetail&idx=000113&addsort=0&sorttype=desc&category=1

Comment: Your **Bottom Bracket** is sealed - no maintenance required/possible. **Breaks** need to be adjusted only when one of the pads rubs the rim (lift the bike and rotate its wheels, they should make plenty of rotations). **Hubs** - the site doesn't specify, but I expect they do not require/need maintenance. Btw it will come a time when your fork will develop play between the stanchions and the boots (maybe 2 years from purchase). A side effect will be that rain water will enter the fork and block its movement.

Comment: Interesting summary made by you, @Vorac. I can't read the details of my bicycle although I have owned it.
Thank you so much for help.

Comment: @Vorac The question did not include a photograph of a bicycle  . In, the United States, bicycles named "cruisers" have a metal covering which covers the roller chain or sprocket chain. How would you k ow that "their bottom bracket is sealed" unless you saw the bike with your eyes or a photograph or a drawing of the bicycle?

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon missed the word 'probably'. My whole comment is guesses/ideas; was I reasonably confident any of them answers the question properly it would have been an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use fenders with good coverage! They will keep most of the dirty spray water off your bike. You'll be surprised how much less oiling your chain needs with proper fenders.

*Proper fenders* means:

- a front fender with a mud flap that reaches within a few centimeters of the road
- a rear fender that starts some centimeters below the chain stays, so that water dripping off does not end up on the chain

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, @bhell
My bicycle doesn't use fender. So, it was always dirty when I have used it. Fender is the root to keep the bicycle clean.

Comment: I should note that fenders are only one part of the solution of your problem (even though you accepted my answer). Letting the bike dry thoroughly while stored is very important as well (as others have mentioned). You should also treat metal parts with a bit of oil or wax at least once before the rainy season. Also, if you have a steel frame, you should treat its interior against corrosion.

Comment: In Colorado, in the United States, when it rains, water gets all over the bicycle chains. A fender over the bicycle tire will prevent water  from being spun off the tire o to a person. When wet wheels spin, water is flug off the tire onto a person's clothing, shirt, pants or skin. However, a fender in the shape of a crescent moon   on the tire does not prevent the chain from rusting or corroding.

Answer (score 4):

- Store your bike in a dry place if possible. This is probably the most important thing - even if you ride every day, your bike spends more time parked than it does on the road.
- Clean and oil the chain regularly. If it's squeaking or showing rust, you're not doing it often enough.
- If you have loose bearings anywhere on your bike (hubs, pedals, bottom bracket, or headset) then take them apart and pack with fresh grease at least once a year. Not applicable if you have sealed bearings - you can just ignore those.

Comment: Thank you for another suggestion, @Mike Baranczak.

It's great!

Comment: According to latest comments under the question, his BB is sealed. His hubs are unspecified, and I am not sure if the cheapest hubs are loose bearings or sealed. The headset is most certainly loose. His pedals are not large platform with pins, which (in my book) means that wearing out the bearings and needing a replacement is a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is not to ride your bike on rainy days at all.
According to your own account, this isn't possible. So:

1. Wipe dry the frame, bottom bracket, hubs, chain, crankset, etc.
2. If possible, use an air blower to keep them dry.
3. Use water-proof parts, like some hubs with a rubber ring to prevent water from getting inside them.
   Also using waterproof grease in hub area is a choice.
4. Choose chain lubricant that contains some wax, this will keep water running off your chain, crankset and cassette instead of staying on them and getting into them.
5. Spread a thin film of oil on metal parts that is prone to corrosion.

Comment: What's a water blower, and how does it keep things dry?

Comment: @andy256 Water blower keeps things dry by blowing water away since you can't wipe dry everything, especially when drying cracks.

Comment: Thank you for another suggestion, @Id0891.
It's great too!